# What is this x86 add instruction doing?

Tags: assembly, x86

1.
    add 0x4(%esp), %eax

Does this mean add 4 to the address in %esp and add that number to what is in %eax or does it mean add 4 to the address stored in %esp and add what is in the resulting address to %eax?

Answer (score 3):

The latter: add 4 to `esp`, take the contents of the resulting address, add them to `eax`, and store in `eax`.

In GNU syntax assembly, the parentheses are used to dereference a pointer. You could view them as loosely analogous to unary `*` in C.

The offset to add before dereferencing comes before and outside the parentheses; you may also see additional arguments such as `4(%esp, %ecx, 4)`, which means to first add `ecx` multiplied by 4 to `esp` before applying the offset. All three of the extra parameters (i.e. other than the register being dereferenced itself, unless the instruction is `lea`) are optional and can be left out, hence the shortened version you found. This isn't a shortcut for multiple machine instructions - it changes the operation of a *single* instruction, and is thus meant to be more efficient than computing offsets mathematically.

For more information, you can read about "addressing modes".

Comment: FWIW, just for those who are more familiar with it, in Intel format that would be `ADD EAX,[ESP+4]`. I personally find that much more readable. And the other example argument would be `[ESP+4+ECX*4]`, which is also more readable, IMO. Still a +1, of course.